# Saving association I.D upon creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a `user` that has_many `user_logins` and a `user_logins` that belongs to `user` - When a user_login is created I'm using UserLogin.create(userlogin_params) and then my strong params permits the user_id column - but this alone is not saving the current users I.D to the column as it is coming out as nil.

How do I make it save the I.D?

Comment: why not use `@user.user_logins.create(userlogin_params)` ?  That will build the association for you.

Comment: Try this: userlogin_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user login_params) before creating UserLogin.

Comment: Ideally, the preferred way is to build it by association - `u = User.find(params[:user_id]); u.user_logins.build(userlogin_params)`. If user_id is coming by form, use accept_nested_attributes_for. 
So it depends on your workflow.

Comment: Be careful which parameters you accept from the user though. If `params[:user_id]` is used, a user could cause a login record to be created for a totally different user.

Answer (score 0):

User model:

```
has_many :user_logins
```

UserLogin model

```
belongs_to :user

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

UserLoginController:

```
...
def create
  @user_login = UserLogin.new(user_login_params)
  ...
end
...
def user_login_params
  param.require(:user_login).permit(
    :user_login_attribute1,
    :user_login_attribute2,
    user_attributes: [
      :id,
      :user_attribute1,
      :user_attribute2
    ]
  )
end
```

Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Avoid permitting any possible attribute like this. Strong parameters exist so you can use parameter white listing for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here at hand.

First: How do you create an association with the parent record automagically there?

Second: How do you do this so your controller action isn't a giant hole waiting for a hacker to stick their nose in.

You need to start from the parent, then build the child, not start with the child and build the parent.

Consider the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logins, class_name: "UserLogin"
end

class UserLogin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserLoginsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if new_user_login(user_login_params).save
      redirect_to :wherever
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def new_user_login(attrs={})
    current_user.logins.create(attrs)
  end

  def user_login_params
    param.require(:user_login).permit(:attr_1, :attr_1)
end
```

Do not pass IDs into any secure params hash unless that ID is selectable by the user. If you allow an ID into secure params, a hacker can start moving records around to other objects and destroy your database integrity.

If you would like pairing help on this problem live and in person, you can check out my codementor profile at https://codementor.io/rubycasts/#reviews